# When executing a query in rails, how do you view/log the actual query being executed?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with a single query to one of my databases, and I think it's because the data I'm passing isn't being inserted correctly. The easiest way I can think of to try and check this would be to see the actual sql generated by my fairly simple query, which I call like so:

```
query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare(query_string)
result = query.execute(start_time, end_time)
```

This query, unfortunately, does not seem to log anything like queries made through activerecord - I have logged queries from before and after it, but the one made with execute says nothing at all. I know it's running the query because it does return results, just the wrong ones.

Is it failing to log the actual query because it's an execute statement? What do I need to do in order to see the actual sql query being sent out to the table here?

Comment: When you run queries through `raw_connection` they are not logged. You would need to manually log the query eg `Rails.logger.info(query.to_s)`.

Comment: I can only log the query string that way - I want to log the final, resulting query.  The one that's actually executed. You're saying there's no way to do that?